# Is Peter Parker considered a good photographer outside his pictures of Spider-Man?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

Peter Parker is hired (sometimes in a freelance, sometimes in a full-time capacity) by J. Jonah Jameson's paper, *The Daily Bugle*, to take pictures of Spider-Man because he is the only one who can get clear pictures of him. Of course, the only reason that is true is because

> Peter Parker is Spider-Man.

Consequently, most storylines set in *The Daily Bugle* involve Peter taking pictures of Spider-Man, not so much anything else. Is there any evidence that he is a great, or even good, photographer outside of taking pictures of Spider-Man, or would he not get any photography work if Spider-Man didn't conveniently pose for him?

Comment: Related: [Has Peter Parker ever received any awards for his photography?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237449/has-peter-parker-ever-received-any-awards-for-his-photography/237455#237455)

Comment: @LogicDictates - More than just 'related' in my opinion.

Comment: @Donatello Swansino - I note that you're asking two slightly different questions here: 1) Is Peter _considered_ a good photographer, outside of his Spider-Man photos? 2) Is there any evidence that he _is_ a good or great photographer outside of his Spider-Man photos? Which if either of those is the question you're most keen to see answered here, as my initial instinct is that the answers to these questions could be meaningfully different.

Comment: @Valorum - I did initially type "Related, possible dupe" but then edited the comment, noticing that most of the evidence submitted in the other thread does relate to Spider-Man photos. I've asked the OP to be a bit more precise about what they're looking for, because depending on how you interpret this question, an answer to this question could conceivably be quite different to the ones in the other thread, but then again, maybe not.

Comment: @LogicDictates I wasn't sure when I initially read the marked question, but upon further investigation, it is clear there are similarities between mine and the older one.

Comment: I included some scans near the end of my answer to the other question that weren't directly relevant to that question, but which I thought would be of interest to people reading it. I think I could put together an answer to this question which is quite distinct from my answer to the other one, but I'd likely remove a few of the less relevant scans from the old answer and use them here instead. I also have a couple of other references in mind which are more relevant to this question than the other one, so it wouldn't be just a case of transferring content from an existing answer.